# Can Google Flogger be configured to write logs in json format?

Tags: java

I am setting up Google flogger as the logging framework for my project and can write the logs in the readable format . I would like to know if it can be configured to write the logs in JSON format , without having to integrate with any other logging framework like log4j2 .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible only via a JUL custom JSON formatter , otherwise it is better to integrate with some back-end logging api .